# Arabic text support for Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I would like to display Arabic text in my Android application. I am developing the application for Android 1.6.

Problem is, when i run the application i can only see square boxes instead of Arabic text.

After google'ing i found the font(*.ttf -true type font) for Arabic has to be added.
[ http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/07/02/how-to-install-and-add-hebrew-arabic-and-unsupported-language-fonts-to-android-phone/ ]. But the solution is for real devices. More over in emulator most of the commands [ex: su,mkdir,chmod etc] are not permitted.

I'm working on windows XP, Eclipse 3.5.2, Android 1.6. All i need is a solution to display Arabic text in emulator.

Any of your effort in this regard is respected from my side:-)

Comment: If you want to set Arabic font in emulator try
[Font installation in emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487976/what-is-the-best-way-of-installing-new-font-to-android-emulator/10487991#10487991)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got solution from my friend for the above said prob..

And sharing the same here..

---

If you are having `.ttf` file then first of all open your project in eclipse and copy `.ttf` file into the assets folder, which will be in your project hierarchy.
and then open `.java` file where you want to use that font and just follow these steps:-

```
First
Typeface font1;
TextView txt1;
EditText edtxt;
```

Second:
In onCreate Method just write down this code.

```
/*here fonttype.ttf is the file which was copied in assets folder.*/

font1 =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonttype.ttf");
txt1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_id_txt);
txt1.setTypeface(font1);

edtx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
edtx.setTypeface(font1);
```

by this your problem will solve.

---

All credits goes to my friend

Answer (score 2):

you can save the XML file in the UTF-8 format