# URDU or Arabic Support in android for emulator and device

Tags: android, encoding, android-emulator

I am developing an application which i need to add urdu language.

The problem is that, when i open this file on browser then urdu words are shown good. but these words are not shown on emulator.

for example

```
محبوب
```

this is shown same as it is on browser but when i see this word to emulator then its shown like this

```
م ح ب و ب
```

I read this post [Arabic text support for Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758016/arabic-text-support-for-android-emulator)
its seems good but it's doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you follow the post you have mentioned[ As it is from me ;) ]

Meanwhile make sure the font file(*.ttf) which has been placed under "assets" folder, supports
the string which you are expecting.

Point is, find a **suitable  font (*.ttf) file** which serves your purpose. Rest will be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the emulator for Android 3 or 4. Older versions of Android did not have support for Arabic shaping.

The limitation was in the Android OS, not the emulator, so even with the new emulators, you should create virtual Andoroid 3/4 devices for this to work.