# URDU or ARABIC in android app

Tags: android, encoding, android-emulator

I would like to add Urdu support to my app. When I open it in a browser then Urdu words are shown fine. But these words are not shown in the emulator.

for example

```
محبوب
```

This is displayed same as it is on browser but when I see this word in the Android emulator then it's displayed like this

```
م ح ب و ب
```

I read the post [Arabic text support for Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3758016/429850), it seems good but it's doesn't work in my case.

Comment: You have to patch you framework file with RTL patch..

Comment: What version of Android where you emulating?

Comment: user Alefonizer @ http://sourceforge.net/projects/alefonizer/  .. it will help you .. I dont know if it supports urdu range