# Arabic Writing in Android

Tags: android, mobile, emulation, arabic

```
myXmlContent.setText("بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ");
```

I am writing the above code and trying to display the text in Arabic.

but every character is being displayed separately in Android emulator.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Complex scripts are currently not fully support by the UI toolkit. We are working on improving this.

Comment: i made the code, but am thinking to make it commercial, what do you think

Answer (score 0):

Don't Worry we faced this on our applications but it works like a charm on the real devices (Samsung htc)
I do advice work and debug directly on real device this is faster and reflects your work In final look.
you may look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3769283/771300

Answer (score 0):

Have look the below link.

[Android Arabic Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885958/android-arabic-language/28193263#28193263)

You need to use Arabic Reshaper utility

Below are the some links https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper

https://mdictionary.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/connected-arabic-characters-for-android-apps/