# Android Arabic Language

Tags: android, arabic

I'm trying to make an app in Arabic Language for Android 2.2. I write a text to code such as:

```
البُرتُقال نوع من أنواع الحمضيات وهو مصدر ممتاز لفيتامين سي ويساعد فيتامين (سي) في البرتقال على امتصاص الكالسيوم في الجسم ، كما يحتوي أيضا على فيتامين أ كما أنه مصدر
```

it is displayed as below:

[image: The same text on android.]

I mean the letters come separately, and that causes the meaning differences. How can I make the letters display connected?

Edit :

Yes 4.0 has the support for Arabic. Now I have to find a way for 2.2, because the product that I use, runs with 2.2. And I can't implement 4.0 to it easyly. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: Have you tried other (more recent) versions of Android?

Comment: Use typeface for your requirement, may be it will help you.
and also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956852/how-to-support-arabic-language-in-android

Comment: Arabic text is quite complicated. In latin text you type 'a', you store 'a' in a text file and then you display the 'a' letter - straightforward. In arabic texts it is more like: you type 'a', store 'b', and display 'a' or 'bc' or 'cd' depending on where that letter is in the word / how letters have to be combined (that's at least my understanding). That does not work without special software support (as you can see) and exactly that is missing in older Android versions.

Comment: @dldnh no, because I needed it on 2.2, but I think I'll have to change the version.

Comment: @RobinHood thanks for the link, it seems like 4.0 will solve the problem. I'll try now.

Comment: @zapl it seemed to me so, but what kind a sw could I use, if 4.0 will not work?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to solve that but try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813 - it's linked in link @RobinHood gave you and should do all the missing conversion.

Comment: You can find your solution [at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/779408). Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

I found an [issue report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5597) about Arabic language support. There was a post just 10 hours ago, that **Android 4.x** adds improved support for reading and writing BiDi text such as Arabic!

Answer (score 0):

You  need to use Arabic Reshaper utility

Below are the some links
https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper

https://mdictionary.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/connected-arabic-characters-for-android-apps/