# Arabic 'disconnected' letters in Android

Tags: android, arabic

I am looking for an app or any library (ready to use) for my smartphone (HTC Desire S with 2.3.5 android, sense 3.0 and NOT deodexed) whici supports arabic language and solves the problem of 'disconnected' letters. I've tried to use some arabic reader app on android market but they didn't solve the issue. I'm not a programmer and I do not know how to change/create jar libraries for it.

Does anybody know whether there's any update or news about it?!

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Almuna. You'll probably want to ask your question on http://android.stackexchange.com/ . This site is only about programming questions.

Comment: Here is another [link][1] that is very relevant to your situation.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885958/android-arabic-language