# How to display Arabic text and numbers in correct format?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

I want to display Arabic Text and symbols and numbers from RTL and in correct format on Android through an Application Development
I used `ArabicReshap` Class, but it just reshaped the Arabic letters, but the symbols made a trouble,

Any body had solved this issue?

Comment: see if this could help you:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758016/arabic-text-support-for-android-emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change in the font, choose FontCreator application to edit the font and replace the any symbol with the letter you want, and replace it in the text.