# Show Numbers In Arabic Format Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

How to show numbers in Arabic format in flutter app?

instead of showing the number as 1,2,3 I need to show them as ١, ٢, ٣

I have tried to use the NumberFormat class, but it doesn't work.

Flutter Doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v0.8.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.345], locale ar-SA)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.27.2)
[√] Connected devices (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      locale: Locale("ar"),
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(NumberFormat().format(1)),
              new Text(NumberFormat().format(2)),
              new Text(NumberFormat().format(3)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487089/how-to-display-arabic-text-and-numbers-in-correct-format (Android native). Perhaps you need to specify a font that shows them as Arabic numbers.

Comment: Where do you specify that the font should be used? https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/fonts/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thanks for your replay. It's really not a flutter issue. I have tried to use a [font](https://fontzone.net/font-details/arabictwo-bold) that supports Arabic numbers and [added it to flutter](https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/fonts/) and it's work.

Comment: Glad to hear \o/

Comment: for me its not working. I tried to add google fonts that supports arabic number

Comment: Not working for me either. The thing i don't understand is that DateFormat can convert date to Arabic numbers but NumberFormat doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

[Adding](https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/fonts/) a [font](https://fontzone.net/font-details/arabictwo-bold) that supports Arabic numbers solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
String convertToArabicNumber(String number) {
  String res = '';

  final arabics = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];
  number.characters.forEach((element) {
     res += arabics[int.parse(element)];
  });

/*   final latins = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']; */
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer so that the others in the community can easily understand your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Using EG (Egypt) as the country code in intl package would solve the issue without needing to add a new font.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
   print(NumberFormat('#.##', 'ar_EG').format(25.46));
}
```

Output:
`٢٥٫٤٦`

Answer (score 1):

This package will do it for you
`arabic_numbers`
https://pub.dev/packages/arabic_numbers

Answer (score 0):

I have published the [`localizeDigits()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hrk_batteries/latest/hrk_batteries/HrkString/localizeDigits.html) extension method on String in the package [`hrk_batteries`](https://pub.dev/packages/hrk_batteries).

Add the package:

```
$ dart pub add hrk_batteries
```

Use it as follows:

[localized_digits_example.dart](https://github.com/hrishikesh-kadam/hrk_batteries.dart/blob/main/example/localized_digits_example.dart)

```dart
import 'package:hrk_batteries/hrk_batteries.dart';

void main() {
  final String enToArLocalizedString = 'A0123456789Z'.localizeDigits(
    toZeroDigit: '\u0660', // toZeroDigit: '٠',
  );
  print(enToArLocalizedString); // A٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩Z
}
```