# How to set arabic font in my android app?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arabic text support for Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758016/arabic-text-support-for-android-emulator)

I would like to set arabic language in my android app. But i unable to use arabic font. Please any boudy help me to use this.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758016/arabic-text-support-for-android-emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to change the language by anagrammatically.

Write the countrycode of language in place of "en_US" whatever language you want. 
 Like for `japanese--"ja_JP" For Arabic--"ar"` or check this link for code of country.

Also See [Languages supported](https://developers.google.com/igoogle/docs/i18n).

And make a folder in `res/values-ar for arabic`.

And make `string.xml` file And put the languages whatever you want on your layout.. It will fetch the default language from values folder otherwise you want it manually then it will fetch from your external folder values-ar etc. like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="spinner_label">تصفية حسب</string>
    <string name="app_name">2011 فرق</string> 
    <string name="search">بحث :</string>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeFace to set any fonts in your App,
You just need to keep your font file in assets and load them to the app as follows,in example font files are kept in folder named fonts in assets
like :

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),"fonts/YourFontFile.ttf");
TextView tv0 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv0.setTypeface(face);
```